# Truncation issue while using netbeans to run a isPrime program

Tags: c, netbeans

When trying to debug a isPrime program, i started running into an warning that would not allowing me to run the program. The warning states `Relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64PC32 against undefined symbol "isPrime(int)"`. I had ran into this problem a while ago but have since forgotten exactly how to deal with it. Is it a problem with  the program that usually causes this, or is it a problem with netbeans and the compiler it uses for C.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(int userInput);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int userInput;
    bool prime = false;
    int again = 0;

    printf("This program will check if a number is Prime\n");

    while(again == 0)
    {
        printf(" Enter number: \n ");
        scanf("%d",&userInput);

        prime = isPrime(userInput);

        if( prime )
            printf("%d is prime.",userInput);
        else
            printf("%d is not prime",userInput);

        printf("again? \n 0 for yes \n 1 for no");
        scanf("%d", &again);
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int userInput)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    bool result = true; 

    while(tmp != 1 && result == true)
    {
        if( userInput % tmp == 0)
            result = false;

        tmp--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

\

Code has been edited

Comment: Where is `isPrime` defined?  There's only a declaration shown.

Comment: `prime == true` may be simplified to `prime`